# Powershell CSOM with PnP AuthenticationManager: flush credentials

Tags: powershell, csom, authentication, pnp, office-dev-pnp

I've been using an `OfficeDevPnp.Core.AuthenticationManager` for a long time, in order to support MFA for PowerShell scripts targeting SharePoint Online with CSOM.

For my current task, DEV is on tenant-1, whereas TEST and PROD are on tenant-2.

I use me@tenant-1.com for DEV, and otherme@tenant-2.com for TEST and PROD.

For some reason today, when switching from DEV to TEST, when I'm expecting to be prompted to authenticate as otherme@tenant-2.com, the auth prompt popped up briefly but for some reason performed authentication with me@tenant-1.com.

Hence, the script failed with a 403 for a CSOM ExecuteQuery() call. Now I can't seem to get it to a state where I can interactively provide my otherme@tenant-2.com credentials for tenant-2. I've even restarted the machine.

My code is nothing special:

```
$siteURL = "https://tenant-2.sharepoint.com/sites/TEST"
$authmgr = new-object OfficeDevPnp.Core.AuthenticationManager
$ctx = $authmgr.GetWebLoginClientContext($siteURL)
```

**Is there a way to flush the credentials cache?** I don't recall having this problem previously; ordinarily I just specify the site URL and if the Authentication Manager can't find a suitable native tenant user, it prompted me for one.

Comment: Duh... delete cookies on the machine. It must be time for a break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. The resolution is to **delete the relevant cookies from the machine**, after which the next execution of the script surfaces the prompt again, in this case allowing me to provide the correct credentials for tenant-2.

Comment: ...I've come back here a few times to remind myself. As of today, I still need to do this using Internet Options via IE or control panel, not Edge/Chrome cache clearing.